# How to absolutely position Bootstrap navbar within div without wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to overlay my navbar onto a background image. The way I'm doing this is nesting it within a div, and using absolute position. However, the `navbar-header`/`navbar-brand` portion causes the rest of the navbar to wrap onto a new line.

Here's the example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/qjxszebe/

I realize there are some other options about creating the background image, but I'd like to understand why this simple approach doesn't work.

What I want is the fiddle above to be fixed such that the navbar is on a single line as you'd expect, not two lines.

**Solution:**
Here's the working fiddle with the width: 100%: https://jsfiddle.net/69yhavtj/

Comment: Not clear. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Clarified: What I want is the fiddle above to be fixed such that the navbar is on a single line as you'd expect, not two lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `width:100%` in your CSS navbar is in the same line, not the bar low.

You should add your image in the `class="img-responsive"` class since your image is not reponsive the way they have done

```
   .navbar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```